# Taking averages of averages

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The numbers $1000$ and $1000000$ are already written on a paper. We are allowed to write down an average of two written numbers, if that average is an *integer* has not been written before, and we can repeat this. How many numbers can we write down at most?

The process of repeatedly taking averages can give rise to weighted average with denominators being powers of two. Those are numbers of the form $a\cdot 1000+(1-a)\cdot 1000000$ for $a=\frac{k}{2^n}$ with $0<k<2^n$. The question then becomes how many of these numbers there are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that if we started from numbers $0$ and $1$, and are not restricted to integers, then we can get all numbers of the form $\frac{k}{2^n}$, where $0 \leq k \leq 2^n$. We prove this by induction on $n$:

- For $n=0$, this is trivially true
- Suppose it is true for $0, 1, 2, \dots n$.

  - If $k$ is even, $k=2a$, we have$\frac{k}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{2a}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{a}{2^n}$, a number achievable by induction on step $n$.
  - If $k$ is odd, $k=2a+1$, we have$\frac{k}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{2a+1}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{a}{2^n}+\frac{a+1}{2^n}\right)$ - the average of two numbers already written on step $n$, thus allowed too.

So, starting from $1000$ and $1000000$, we can get precisely any number of the form $1000 + (1000000-1000)\frac{k}{2^n}$, where $0 \leq k \leq 2^n$. For this to be an integer, $2^n$ should divide $1000000-1000=999000$. Since $999000=2^33^35^337$, we obtain $n \leq 3$.